# Trace Words in Shell Script

Tags: regex, shell

I am trying to find malloc-free series. Consider that we have 1000s of test cases. People may forget to free ptr. Please help me in optimizing the script.

#### Sample File Under test

```
Test(func_class,func1)
{
  int i,j;
  char* ptr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
  free(ptr);
}

Test(func_class,func1)
{
  int i,j;
  char* ptr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
  / Memory Leak / 
}
```

#### Script under development :

```
export MY_ROOT=`pwd`
_COUNT=0
pwd
_COUNT_WORD=0
filename=test.c
cat $filename | while read line
do 
    echo "Reading Line = $LINE" 
    for word in $line
    do
    _COUNT_WORD=$(($_COUNT_WORD+1))
    echo $_COUNT_WORD $word    
    if [ "$word" == "malloc\(sizeof\(char\)\);" ]; then    
        _MALLOC_FLAG=1   #this part of the code is not reached
        echo "Malloc Flag Hi"
        echo $word[2]
    fi
    done
    _COUNT_WORD=0
done
```

I have some issue in matching the malloc regex. I know the script needs a lot of modifications as we have to find the pattern of individual person writing malloc.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to check:

**Using awk:**

```
awk '/malloc/ || /free/{count++;}END{printf "%d",count}' fileundertest
```

This will search for "malloc" and "free" words in file and will print out the count. if count is even you can say for every malloc there is free.

**Using grep:**

```
grep -c "malloc" fileundertest
```

This will count the malloc word in file

Similarly,

```
grep -c "free" fileundertest
```

To list out the line number

```
grep -n "malloc" fileundertest
```